# I've populated the dimensions - how to populate the fact table?

Tags: loading, data-warehouse, dimension, fact-table, datamart

I've populated 4 dimensions tables these being a time dim, site dim, abandoned dim and worktype dim.

I've calculated the measures needed in the end fact table in a staging table but how do I transfer the dimension ID's and the measures into the fact table?

The fact table should end up with these columns

```
TimeID  -  SiteId  -  AbandonedID  -  WorkTypeID  -  HoldTime  -  ACWTime  -  RingTime    TalkTime
```

The data will need to be grouped also by the 4 dimension ID's.

Answer (score 1):

A simple JOIN should do the trick. Do an INSERT...SELECT from your staging table to the target table. The staging table should have the measures and the natural keys for each dimension on it, do 4 joins, one to each dim, on the natural keys to get the surrogate keys, and insert into the fact.

Comment: yeah i can get the measures and the actually ID's across but its pulling way way to many rows across and not joining correctly,

I'm unsure how to do the joins.
I need to join a time ID where it fits in between the start and end time in the measures table.
Then i to join to a abandoned ID to the correct abandoned value in the measures table
The site ID needs to be joined to the correct value in the site value in the measures table
And the work type the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your data model? It would be helpful to understand your natural keys for each dim, and what the staging table's structure is.

Comment: Im unsure how I can add the data model? Its a star schema design so all the dimensions are linked to the fact table.
The staging table is not linked it just holds the values for the measures aswell as a few more useful attributes

Comment: There should be a 1:1 relationship between the natural key in your stage table and the surrogate key in the dimension table. Instead of trying to find a TimeID that fits "in between" start and end times, you should have 2 separate foreign keys, one for the start time and one for the end time.

Comment: RichardC As @VictorHDC says, you should have a time ID for the start time and a time ID for the end time. These are called "role-playing" dimensions, where the same dimension plays multiple roles on the fact table. When I asked for the data model, I mean the Table structures (i.e. "time dim" with a list of relevant columns and data types, "staging table", etc). There's a site, SQLFiddle.com, which you can build the DDL and provide a link so it's easier for us to understand what you're trying to do and where it's causing problems.